# Can you use Silent Image and Illusory Reality to create a real tarrasque?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, wizard, illusion

In my campaign there is a level 14 illusion wizard who has used the Illusory Reality feature and *silent image* to create a real mind-controlled tarrasque.

Then he used Malleable Illusions to make it into a gem that he would later one-shot our big bad with.

This powergaming is ruining my campaign! Is this legal or am I missing something? If it's legal, what do I do to fix my game?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

From your question I get that player in question used Illusory Reality to make illusionary tarrasque real. However it is impossible by RAW:

> When you cast an illusion spell of 1st level or higher, you can choose one **inanimate**, nonmagical object that is part of the illusion and make that object real.
>   [...]
>   The object **can't deal damage** or otherwise directly harm anyone.

Comment: In addition to this and the size limitation, Illusory Reality only makes the object real for one minute while the spell is ongoing. Furthermore, Malleable Illusions also states: "Starting at 6th level, when you cast an illusion spell that has a duration of 1 minute or longer, you can use your action to change the nature of that illusion (using the spell's normal parameters for the illusion), provided that you can see the illusion." Basically, the player in question seems to be ignoring virtually every rule specified by the various abilities he's using.

Answer (score 16):

Dont forget that [Silent Image](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/silent-image) has a size limitation:

> You create the image of an object, a creature, or some other visible phenomenon that is **no larger than a 15-foot cube**.

Assuming that the tarrasque is the required size, then I would recommend talking to him out of character. If that doesn't work, then you could just have him lose control; after all, it is just a tarrasque that is resistant to charm.

Comment: You may want to quote the size limitation on silent image to improve this answer.

Comment: As a non-native speaker, does “15-foot cube” describe a cube with 15 ft. long edges or 15 ft.³ (cubic feet) of volume? I tend to think the former since rules try to use simple maths and 15 is no cubic number.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Usually "15 foot cube" would be 15 by 15 by 15, and "15 cubic feet" would be the same volume as 15 by 1 by 1

Comment: Please include the size of a Tarrasque in your answer. According to reddit, it's 50 feet tall and 70 feet long.

Comment: @DavidFoerster that is explictly explained in the beginning of the Spellcasting chapter.

Comment: @Rubiksmoose Yes, it is. "The cube’s size is expressed as the length of each side.", it's under the Areas of Effect section, Cube subsection in the Spellcasting chapter. I'm just not sure I'm answering what you think I'm answering :P